# Wpf binding: How to avoid "property not found" runtime errors at design time

Tags: wpf, testing

I would like to somehow ensure, that all my bindings in xaml binds to existing property.

I want to avoid runtime errors like this:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Fullname' property not found on 'object' ''Person' (HashCode=33132859)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=Person.Fullname; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=46007650); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Every view has specified type of datacontext using d:DesignInstance and every DataTemplate uses DataType attribute if it cannot be inherited from context (e.g ListBoxItem template).

In visual studio xaml designer, invalid properties are underlined and at runtime I get binding errors in output window.

is there any tool, that could check those errors? I was thinking about some automated UI test, that would go trough entire application and check debug output, but it's quite hard to setup.

if resharper can parse xaml and identify invalid bindings, at least theoretically it should be possible to do it in code analysys or unit tests.

EDIT:
I have added suggestion to uservoice: https://wpf.uservoice.com/forums/40688-general/suggestions/7423474-strongly-typed-binding-testability
Vote please!

Answer (score 4):

I liked this solution:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130505005640/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors. 
Every time a binding fails, you get a popup message.

Edit: As requested, here is the source code of the BindingErrorTraceListener, written by [Michael Kuehl](http://tech.pro/mkuehl), including a bugfix by [Jesse Chisholm](http://tech.pro/Bv1WHnZ) (send the MessageBox to the GUI thread via the Dispatcher).

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace SOTC_BindingErrorTracer
{
  public class BindingErrorTraceListener : DefaultTraceListener
  {
    private static BindingErrorTraceListener _Listener;

    public static void SetTrace()
    { SetTrace(SourceLevels.Error, TraceOptions.None); }

    public static void SetTrace(SourceLevels level, TraceOptions options)
    {
      if (_Listener == null)
      {
        _Listener = new BindingErrorTraceListener();
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(_Listener);
      }

      _Listener.TraceOutputOptions = options;
      PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = level;
    }

    public static void CloseTrace()
    {
      if (_Listener == null)
      { return; }

      _Listener.Flush();
      _Listener.Close();
      PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Remove(_Listener);
      _Listener = null;
    }



    private StringBuilder _Message = new StringBuilder();

    private BindingErrorTraceListener()
    { }

    public override void Write(string message)
    { _Message.Append(message); }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
      _Message.Append(message);

      var final = _Message.ToString();
      _Message.Length = 0;

      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
          new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { MessageBox.Show(final, "Binding Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, 
        MessageBoxImage.Error); return null; }), 
          null);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your Window, or your View base class, add the line

```
BindingErrorTraceListener.SetTrace();
```

to turn the popups on.

Comment: I was just about to write my own trace listener. This definitelly saves me couple of hours, thank you! Now I need to find out how go trought all views and and their viewmodels in my integration test and make the tests fail if there is a binding error.

Comment: This is a great snippet of code... but can you move the actual code into the answer, so that we don't lose this via link rot? I'll gladly +1 this answer after the code inline'd. Don't forget to include attibution.